# How to convert a binary string into base64 encoded data

Tags: c++, class, encoding, base64, binary-data

I am receiving binary data in a string. I want to encode that into Base64. Is there any class to do that operation (I want an API).

Comment: What language(s) are you familiar with?

Answer (score 4):

[CryptBinaryToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
...if you target to Windows platform

Here is a little sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")

int main()
{
    LPCSTR pszSource = "Man is distinguished, not only by his reason, but ...";
    DWORD nDestinationSize;
    if (CryptBinaryToString(reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*> (pszSource), strlen(pszSource), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, nullptr, &nDestinationSize))
    {
        LPTSTR pszDestination = static_cast<LPTSTR> (HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, nDestinationSize * sizeof(TCHAR)));
        if (pszDestination)
        {
            if (CryptBinaryToString(reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*> (pszSource), strlen(pszSource), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, pszDestination, &nDestinationSize))
            {
                // Succeeded: 'pszDestination' is 'pszSource' encoded to base64.
            }
            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, pszDestination);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is windows only answer