# Send images via sockets in C++

Tags: c++, image, sockets, char, send

I'm trying to send an image in C++ using sockets.

The problem I'm facing is reading the image as binary base64 and then inserting it in a char array in order to send it.

I would really appreciate if you can help me or give me a tip on how to read the image as binary base64 then insert it into a char array.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385319/how-to-convert-the-binary-string-into-base64-encode-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first read the file as binary. And then use the read buffer to encode as base64 and send it over to the recipient. Try readying binaryIO in C++ and there are a lot of base64 libraries e.g. apache , openssl etc.

For Binary IO.
[Read binary file c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162601/read-binary-file-c)
http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2604/fall02/binio.html

Base64 :
[how to convert the binary string into base64 Encode data..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385319/how-to-convert-the-binary-string-into-base64-encode-data)